# How to Resolve "Cannot access 'mockKeycloak' before initialization" Error in Jest and VITest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, vitest

I'm writing tests using Jest and VITest for a React application. I've encountered an error related to the initialization order of mock functions and variables. The error message is "Cannot access 'mockKeycloak' before initialization." I believe this is occurring due to the order in which my mock setups and test code are executed.

Here's a simplified version of my test code:

```
// Import statements...

let mockKeycloak = {};
vi.mock("keycloak-js");

const mockKeycloak = {
  init: vi.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  updateToken: vi.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  createLoginUrl: vi.fn(() => "mock-login-url"),
  token: "mock-token",
  authServerUrl: "mock-auth-url",
  realm: "mock-realm",
};

vi.mock("keycloak-js", () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockKeycloak),
  };
});

// Other mock setups...

describe("My Test Suite", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // ... Initialization code ...
  });

  test("My test case", async () => {
    // ... Test logic ...
  });
});
```

The issue seems to be that the mockKeycloak definition is not available when it's being used in the vi.mock() setup. How can I resolve this error and properly organize my test code to ensure that the mock setup for keycloak-js is done before other code that relies on it?

Additional Context:

I'm using VITest for testing.
The error is occurring specifically in relation to the vi.mock("keycloak-js", ...) setup.
The rest of the test code includes render logic, assertions, and other test cases.
I've attempted reordering my code, but I'm unsure of the correct approach to ensure proper initialization order.
Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!